# What does it mean to be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

I've come across a similar idea before. For instance, one can define $\mathbb{R}^n$ as the set of all n-tuples of real numbers. From this, we could say that $\underline {v_1} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ means $\underline {v_1}$ is some n-tuple of real values.

I suppose we could take more n-tuples in this fashion, $\underline{v_2},\underline{v_3},\underline{v_4}$, and so on. From this, we could define $V=\{{\underline {v_1}, \underline{v_2},\underline{v_3},\underline{v_4} \}}$. In other words, $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$.

But then I came across the definition of a convex set:

A set $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is convex if for all $x_1,x_2\in X$ and all $p\in [0,1]$,

$px_1 + (1-p)x_2 \in X$

This definition is then followed up by a more "intuitive version": A set $X$ is convex if you can take any two points in $X$ and draw a straight line between them, and every point on the line is also in $X$. This is accompanied by images like this:

[image: a convex set]

Then I try and reconcile that with my idea of what a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ was before I came across the definition of a convex set.

$X$ must be some set similar to $V$, consisting of some number of n-tuples of real values. If that's the case, then perhaps that means $x_1$ and $x_2$ are n-tuples.

I imagine if you want to create the image of the green set, then $X$ is a set of 1-tuples (just a set of regular numbers I suppose) -- as in a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ ($\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n=1$). In which case $x_1$ and $x_2$ are just numbers like $4$ and $11$ -- a pair of numbers that satisfy the definition of a convex set.

In that case, I expect I don't need to modify my understanding of what a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is.

If my thoughts on these concepts are correct, then I suppose there isn't a problem. Nevertheless, I want to be sure, so I thought I'd ask the question: what does it mean to be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Your intuition of $V$ is correct enough, but only works for very small subsets. For instance, thinking of $\Bbb Q\subseteq \Bbb R^1$ that way is pushing it, and thinking of $\Bbb R^1\subseteq \Bbb R^1$ as a list of elements in that way is provably impossible.

Comment: I'm .... having a very hard time understanding your issue.  So far as I can tell, the definition of subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is a set of $n$-tuples is in no way in conflict with the definition of convex.  Why do you think it is an issue?

Comment: In $\mathbb R^1$ a convex set is nothing more than an interval.  $K \subset \mathbb R$ is convex is if $a<b$ and $a,b, \in K$ then for every $x; a\le x \le b$ then $x\in K$.  So the GREEN so if $x=4$ and $y = 11$ then GREEN will be something like $(3,12)$ or $(-\infty, 19)$ or $[3.9, 11.7]$ or ... whatever.

Comment: You seem to be thinking that if GREEN is convex it must somehow "squish" it's elements down to 1-tuples.  I'm not sure why you are thinking that.  The *line* is i) 1-dimensional and ii) straight, but it is a one-dimensional line *IN* an $n$-dimensional space.  The points that make up the line are (like *everything* in the space) $n$-tuples.  Not 1-tuples.  The relationship that "two points in $n$-dimensional space are in a line" needs to be formally defined.  ANd that's what the $p \in [0,1]$ biz is all about.... to be continued.....

Comment: ...continued... if $X=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $Y=(y_1,y_2,y_3)$ then the points of the line connecting them are $Z= (x_1 + t*(y_1-x_1),x_2 + t*(y_2-x_2), x_2 + t*(y_3-x_3))=X+tY$.  If we replace $t$ with $1-p$ we get $z = (px_1 +(1-p)y_1, px_2 + (1-p)y_2, px_3+(1-p)y_3)= pX + (1-p)Y$.  And in this way we know that $Z$ is "to the right of $Y$" if $p < 0$.  $Z=Y$ if $p=0$.  $Z$ is between $X$ and $Y$ if $0< p <1$ and $Z=X$ if $p=1$, and $Z$ is "to the left of $X$" if $p > 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the single element $x$ and the single element $y$ and the set of all points in the "green set" (of which $x$ and $y$ are members of) are all in the same "space".

In this drawing that space is $\mathbb R^2$ and $x = (a,b)$ and $y=(c,d)$ for some values of $a,b,c,d$ and $GREEN= \{(x,y)|x\in \mathbb R; y\in \mathbb R;$ for some but not all possible values$\}$.  $GREEN$ is such that as $(a,b) \in GREEN$ and $(c,d) \in GREEN$ then for every possible value $p: 0\le p \le 1$ that the point $(p*a + (1-p)*c, p*b+(1-p)*d)$ is in $GREEN$.

If the space in $\mathbb R^n$ and $n\ge 1$ then $GREEN$ is set of $n$-tuples so that of any $X= (x_1,x_2, ....,x_n)$ , $Y=(y_1,y_2, .... y_n)\in GREEN$ then for any $p: 0\le p \le 1$ then the $n-tuple$  $pX+ (1-p)Y := (px_1+ (1-p)y_1,px_2+ (1-p)y_2,........,,px_n+ (1-p)y_n)$.

So yes.... a subset is a collection of $n$-tuples and the definition of "convex" in no way implies anything else.

========

Now if you want to see $x$ as a one-tuple, and $n=1$ that that would make $GREEN$ a subset of $\mathbb R^1 = \mathbb R$.  And $GREEN$ has the property that if $a,b \in GREEN$ then for every $p; 0\le p \le 1$ then $pa+(1-p)b \in GREEN$.

Note that if we assume, without lack of generality, that $a < b$ then $a = pa + (1-p)a < pa + (1-p)b < pb + (1-p)b = b$.  So if $GREEN \subset \mathbb R$ then $GREEN$ is convex if for every $a,b \in GREEN; a< b$ then all $[a,b]\subset GREEN$.  In other words in $R^1$ convex means nothing more or less than $GREEN$ is a (possibly infinite, maybe closed/maybe open) interval.

Comment: Thank you for being so thorough! May I ask, when you say $(pa+(1−p)c,pb+(1−p)c)$ is in GREEN, should there be a $d$ in there somewhere?

Comment: Yeah, the $b,d$s are in the "$y$" slot and the $a,c$ in the "$x$" slot.  So that $c$ in the "$y$" slot was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote “I imagine if you want to create the image of the green set, then $X$ is a set of $1$-tuples (just a set of regular numbers I suppose)”. No. That example (the green set) is a subset of the plane. In other words, it's a subset of $\mathbb R^2$. Each  element of $X$ is an ordered pair of real numbers. If $X$ was a set of numbers, then it would be a subset of the real *line*.

It seems to me that you are not taking into account the possibility that $X$ is an *infinite* subset of $\mathbb R^2$.